# Цикл выполняет все действия сразом

Tags: python

Всем здрасьте. Делаю крестики-нолики. Столкнулся с такой проблемой: создал цикл, который должен менять текст на 1 из 9 раномных кнопках. При этом цикл повторяется 4 раза и текст меняется сразу же на 4 кнопках, хотя надо, чтобы он делал это по очереди. Получается должно быть так: я делаю ход, потом цикл делает ход и тд. А получается я запускаю программу и он сразу делает 4 хода

```
for i in range(4):
    c = int(uniform(1,9))
    if (c==1):
        h1['text']='O'
    if (c==2):
        h2['text']='O'
    if (c==3):
        h3['text']='O'
    if (c==4):
        h4['text']='O'
    if (c==5):
        h5['text']='O'
    if (c==6):
        h6['text']='O'
    if (c==7):
        h7['text']='O'
    if (c==8):
        h8['text']='O'
    if (c==9):
        h9['text']='O'
```

Comment: Могли бы скинуть код полностью, вместе с вашим ходом

Comment: А где у вас в цикле хоть какая нибудь задержка, например ожидание ввода пользователя ?

Comment: А это как-то можно реализовать? Я пока что не понимаю просто

Comment: Как то можно. Но в вопросе не указано, через что вы вообще взаимодействуете с пользователем. Если бы это была просто консоль я бы сказал использовать input(), но раз у вас там какие то кнопки, значит у вас там какая то библиотека пользовательского интерфейса и как именно что либо запрашивать у пользователя должно быть сказано у нее в документации

Comment: Модуль tkinter, кнопки реализованы с помощью оператора Button

Comment: цикл в этом месте не уместен

Comment: А как вообще можно реализовать задуманную мной идею: чтобы после моего хода рандомным образом менялся текст на какой-либо кнопке, симуляируя таким образом ИИ?